# XPages: @DbName() removes slashes from the database filepath

Tags: xpages

I'm using @DbName() to get the name and filepath of a notes database. Unfortunately the filepath and name are returned as one string without slashes. For example, if the filepath is "Dir1/Dir2/dbname.nsf", it is returned as "Dir1Dir2dbname.nsf". Is there any way of getting the filepath with the slashes included?

Comment: What version of Notes/Domino are you using? I recall something like this years ago (first beta release of XPages).

Comment: I'm using version 8.5.3 with sp1 (extensions library) installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @DBName() function call should be used as a list array. The following sample details how to use and what output you get.

**CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:table><xp:tr>
    <xp:td>
        <xp:label value="Field 1 (@DbName as a string) " id="label1">
        </xp:label>
    </xp:td><xp:td>
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:return @DbName();}">
        </xp:text>
    </xp:td>
    </xp:tr><xp:tr>
    <xp:td>
        <xp:label value="Field 2 (@DbName used as list)" id="label2">
        </xp:label>
    </xp:td><xp:td>
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var database = @Subset(@DbName(), -1);
            var server = @Name("[CN]", @Subset(@DbName(), 1));
            return database + " on " + server
            }]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
    </xp:td></xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Field 1 (@DbName as a string)   CN=testserver/O=testorg,subdir\Test.nsf
Field 2 (@DbName used as list)  subdir\Test.nsf on testserver
```

If you are not getting these results, please update your question with sample code.

The other thing to check is if the "\" is being translated as an escape character in your code.

Comment: "The other thing to check is if the "\" is being translated as an escape character in your code." - This was indeed the problem. I was using var database = "#{javascript:@Subset(@DbName(), -1)}"; However, the backslash was removed from the database variable. I've found a workaround by putting the formula @Subset(@DbName(), 1) into a computed field and getting the value using dojo. var fp = "#{id:filename}"; var fpath = dojo.byId(fp).innerHTML; Is there an easier way of doing his?

Comment: an easier way is to use var fpath = "#{javascript:escape(@Subset(@DbName(), -1))}";. fpath includes %5C rather than a backslash.

Comment: Great! glad to see you are sorted.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced something similar and the fix was indeed to use the following to make sure that backslashes are escaped (instead of being interpreted as an escape character):

```
escape(database.getFilePath())
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting this in a computed field or are you using this in some formula?
here is another way.

database.getFilePath()

That should give you Dir/dbname

Comment: The problem was in fact javascript related. See my above comment.